# Google Bigquery, BrowserTool - query runs, but not when I define a destination table

Tags: google-bigquery

I am using the Browser Tool.

The query executes perfectly when I just "Run Query", but when I Enable Options and define a Destination Table I get an error:

Error: record.subject.Equity_Code is not a field of either table in the join
Job ID: robotic-weft-474:job_6IDQeNNhONJRttK6P-44a9rNqkE

Here is the query:

```
SELECT
IF(record.subject.Tax_ID=record.comp.Tax_ID,"subj","") as subj_comp,
record.subject.Tax_ID,
record.subject.Equity_Code,
comp_group.num_comps,
comp_group.median,
FROM
(
SELECT* 
FROM
    (
    SELECT *
    FROM [flat_file.dallas_flatfile]
    WHERE 
        Assessed_Value>=1000000
        AND Division_Code="COM"
        AND Type_Code="OFFICE/SHOWROOM"
    ) as subject
JOIN EACH
    (
    SELECT *
    FROM [flat_file.dallas_flatfile]
    ) as comp
ON subject.Equity_Code=comp.Equity_Code
) as record
   JOIN EACH
(
SELECT
    subject.Tax_ID,
    count(distinct comp.Tax_ID) as num_comps,
    NTH(50,QUANTILES(comp.Assessed_Value/comp.Equity_SQFT,101)) as median,  
FROM
    (
    SELECT *
    FROM [flat_file.dallas_flatfile]
    WHERE 
        Assessed_Value>=1000000
        AND Division_Code="COM"
        AND Type_Code="OFFICE/SHOWROOM"
    ) as subject
JOIN EACH
    (
    SELECT *
    FROM [flat_file.dallas_flatfile]
    ) as comp
ON subject.Equity_Code=comp.Equity_Code
WHERE NOT subject.Tax_ID=comp.Tax_ID
GROUP EACH BY subject.Tax_ID
) as comp_group
ON record.subject.Tax_ID=comp_group.subject.Tax_ID
```